# Patching a program in IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows

I've opened a simple Hello World program in `IDA` (Pro 7.5) like that:

```
    global  _main
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    push    message2
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World 1', 0xD, 0xA, 0 
message2:
    db  'Hello, World 2', 0xD, 0xA, 0
```

Now i've made a simple `detour` - moved the `code` and `data` definition to the unused end of the `code` segment like this:

```
str1  db 'Hello, World1',0Dh,0Ah,0
                                         ; DATA XREF: .text:detour↓o
str2  db 'Hello, World2',0Dh,0Ah,0
                                         ; DATA XREF: .text:00404057↓o
str3  db 'Hello, World3',0Dh,0Ah,0
                                         ; DATA XREF: .text:00404064↓o↓o
      db    0
      db    0
 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 detour:                                 ; CODE XREF: .text:_main↑j
   push    offset str1     ; "Hello, World 1\r\n"
   call    _printf
   add     esp, 4
   push    offset str2     ; "Hello, World 2\r\n"
   call    _printf
   add     esp, 4
   push    offset str3     ; "Hello, World 3\r\n"
   call    _printf
   add     esp, 4
   jmp     go_back
```

Leaving in the `main` function only the `jmp` code like that:

```
_main:                                 
  jmp detour
go_back:                              
  retn
```

And this yeiled me a problem. The output of the patched program is :

```
Hello, World1

Hello, World2

Hello, World3

ABh@@Hello, World2

Hello, World3

ABh@@Hello, World3

ABh@@
```

Instead just:

```
Hello, World 1
Hello, World 2
Hello, World 3
```

It turned out that the patching process just changed the last byte of each string from "00" to "0A"(line feed char)!. There is the screenshot of the `data` section from IDA debugger running:
[image]

And the the `code` section:
[image]
That's the reason of that fucked up output. But the question is WHY does it happened?

Comment: How did you patch the binary? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @sudhackar Just the standard way : first selected __Patch program->Change byte...__ and next __Patch program->Apply patches to input file...__

Comment: @sudhackar Can You please answer my question?